# Make JSF resources publicly accessible with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsf, spring-security

I have implemented spring security in my jsf application. Everything is working fine except static resources require authentication. This is my configuration

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();

    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/register", "/resources/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
           .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
}
```

After doing some google search, most solutions was to add mvc resource tag.

```xml
  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"
    cache-period="31556926"/>
```

I found Similar annotation and added a configuration class for this

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    // equivalents for <mvc:resources/> tags
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

    // equivalent for <mvc:default-servlet-handler/> tag
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

But still static resources require authentication. Some help would be nice about how to make this work.

Note: my resources are placed in `/src/main/webapp/resources/{css|js|image}`. And the problem is if user is not logged in, effect of css, js does not show in the login page. After a user is logged in once, then come to login page after login, css effect appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF managed library resources are served from the `/javax.faces.resource/**` path. So you need to make that path publicly accessible:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();

    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/register", "/javax.faces.resource/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Access_Denied");
}
```

You might also want those resources to be cached by the browser. Then, add this piece to your configuration, which adds a header writer for each of the responses that match a request for `/javax.faces.resource/**`:

```
http.headers()
        .addHeaderWriter(new DelegatingRequestMatcherHeaderWriter(
                new AntPathRequestMatcher("/javax.faces.resource/**"),
                new HeaderWriter() {

                    @Override
                    public void writeHeaders(HttpServletRequest request,
                            HttpServletResponse response) {
                        response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=86400");
                    }
                }))
        .defaultsDisabled();
```

**See also:**

- [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Comment: I added "/javax.faces.resource/**". Unfortunately this makes whole site authorized to non logged in users. Everyone can access everything without logging in.

Comment: yes! I did tried with "/javax.faces.resource/** several times but I missed this .antMatchers("/**").authenticated() every time. So my site was public always